# Proof that Kronecker Delta is Mixed Tensor

Tags: transformation, tensors, kronecker-symbol

The book I am reading asks the reader to verify that the Kronecker Delta is a second-order mixed tensor with one contravariant and one covariant index as indicated:

$$ \delta_j^i =  \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &  i = j\\
0 &  i \neq j
\end{array}
\right.$$

By definition, if it were such a tensor we would have:

$$ {\delta'}_j^i = \delta_l^k \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_k}}\frac{\partial{x_l}}{\partial{x_j}'}$$

using the summation convention.  I have seen a "proof" of this equation somewhere else that goes on to say:

$$ {\delta'}_j^i = \delta_k^k \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_k}}\frac{\partial{x_k}}{\partial{x_j}'} = \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_j}'} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &  i' = j'\\
0 &  i' \neq j'
\end{array}
\right.$$

supposedly verifying it by using the fact that ${\delta}_l^k = 0$ if $ k \neq l$.

However, since k is a dummy index that gets summed over, shouldn't we have 
$$ {\delta'}_j^i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
n &  i' = j'\\
0 &  i' \neq j'
\end{array}
\right.$$

where n is the dimension of the space?

For example, if *i' = 1, j' = 1, n = 2,* wouldn't the transformation equation above give:

$$ {\delta'}_1^1 = \delta_1^1 \frac{\partial{x_1}'}{\partial{x_1}}\frac{\partial{x_1}}{\partial{x_1}'} + \delta_2^2 \frac{\partial{x_1}'}{\partial{x_2}}\frac{\partial{x_2}}{\partial{x_1}'} = 2 $$

where I've used $\delta_1^2 = \delta_2^1 = 0$?  Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure both $\frac{\partial x_1'}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1'} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial x_1'}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1'} = 1$?

Comment: Very good point!  I was haphazardly treating them like fractions i.e. a/b * b/a = a/a * b/b = 1.  However, I see what you mean:  Factoring out the kroneckers, which are each 1, gives us 1*(total chain ruled derivative of x1' with respect to x1'), which is 1*1 = 1.  That clears it up, thank you.

Comment: How do you get ${\delta'}_j^i = \delta_k^k \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_k}}\frac{\partial{x_k}}{\partial{x_j}'}$ ?