# How to show Kronecker delta is tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

The Kronecker delta  is

> [image]

and I use the definition of tensor as

> [image]

I try to prove the Kronecker delta is a (1,1) tensor. I find the [following equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870914/proof-that-kronecker-delta-is-mixed-tensor) which is enough to show Kronecker delta  is a tensor.
$$
{\delta'}_j^i = \delta_k^k \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_k}}\frac{\partial{x_k}}{\partial{x_j}'}
$$
But I dnot know how to get the equation.

Comment: The way proving something is a tensor usually works is that you'll want to change its basis in two ways: from definition (i.e. anything that doesn't use the change of coordinates formula) and then the change of coordinates formula, then show the two are/are not the same, depending on what the object is.

Comment: I am providing you a link. Please go through it, you will find your answer. The link is : Mathematical Methods for Physicists. DOI: 10.1016/B978-0-12-384654-9.00004-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just chain rule applied to the composition:

$$ (x_1' , \cdots, x_n') \mapsto  (x_1 , \cdots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1' , \cdots, x_n')$$

Note that the composition is the identity. So 
$$ I = \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}$$

in terms of index we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial{x_i}'}{\partial{x_k}}\frac{\partial{x_k}}{\partial{x_j}'}= {\delta'}^i_j
\end{align*}